# how to retrieve Common data for Sentinel-1, Sentinel-2 and Landsat-8 on same study area

Tags: arraylist, google-earth-engine, landsat, sentinel1

I am an amateur to GEE, Can anyone help me the script to retrieve Common data for **Sentinel-1, Sentinel-2, or Landsat-8** on the same study area?
I require all the three sensor's data for same-day in the same study area. This is for **comparing** and validating the sentinel-1'SAR data with optical data (sentinel-2 or Landsat-8). The script should return the **dates of the common acquisition by satellites** in the same study area.